# A little magic for the Euler-Lagrange equations?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Consider a simple, one-dimensional Lagrangian:

```
L = m (z'[t]^2)/2 - m g z[t]
```

The built-in, partial-derivative operator `D` has no trouble producing the Euler-Lagrange equations of motion for this:

```
D[D[L, z'[t]],t] - D[L,z[t]] == 0
```

> ```
> g m + m z''[t] == 0
> ```

The same idea works when there are several dynamical variables, say something like

```
L = m (x'[t]^2 + y'[t]^2) / 2;
MapThread[Function[{q, v, h}, D[D[L,v],t] - D[L,q] == h], 
  {{x[t], y[t]}, {x'[t], y'[t]}, {fx[t], fy[t]}}]
```

> ```
> {m x''[t] == fx[t], m y''[t] == fy[t]}
> ```

This is really great and convenient and I use it a lot, but it's occurred to me that it's a little magical. I read the documentation for `D` and the second argument seems always to be just a variable like `x` or `t`, not an extended expression like `x[t]` or `x'[t]`, which is really `Derivative[1][x][t]` or, equivalently, `D[x[t],t]`.

The idea does work when the second argument of `D` is an arbitrary, though unknown function:

```
D[exp[t]^2 / 2, exp[t]]
```

> ```
> exp[t]
> ```

But not when the second argument is a built-in:

```
D[Exp[t]^2 / 2, Exp[t]]
```

> ```
> General: Exp[t] is not a valid variable.
> ```

This message is hard to grok because `exp[t]` isn't exactly a valid variable either, or is it? Are expressions like `x[t]` and `x'[t]` always considered "variables" by `D`? If so, are there other kinds of expressions that `D` thinks of as variables?

This all makes sense, in a way, but is a little surprising and made me curious. Did I miss something in the documentation? Did I not understand the documentation? Is this an under-documented feature? What are the limitations of this feature?

**EDIT**:

I found, by researching "related questions," that

```
D[Log[x]^2 / 2, Log[x]]
```

> ```
> Log[x]
> ```

works as expected. So, it seems, `D` works on *some* built-ins. I'm more confused than ever.

Comment: Note that `Exp[t]` becomes `Power[E, t]`.  It seems to be `Power` that is prevented from being a variable.  Neither are `Times[E, 2]` nor `Plus[E, 2]` valid variables. The start of a pattern? (Arithmetic operations.)

Comment: AFAIR, you used to be able to do this and get the "right" answer: `D[Cos[Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}]], Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}]]`.  But they went and hid unique annotations in the output generated by `Plot` so you cannot generate the same plot twice. [Pointless workaround: `D[Cos[Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}]] /. Annotation -> (# &), Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}] /. Annotation -> (# &)]`]

Comment: Why not use `VariationalMethods\`EulerEquations`?

Comment: @Alexandros (sorry no Greek keyboard installed) maybe I just stumbled on legacy. I typed in the most dumbest thing for E-L and it just worked. I know full well it's a bad pun (see Sussman and Wisdom), but I was pleasantly surprised and went with it to "get stuff done." But then I started to wonder "this is too easy and shouldn't work." Hence the question :)

Comment: @MichaelE2 "Oh what a tangled web we weave, when first we practice to deceive." I got a chuckle out of your revelation!